# Angular ag-grid customized aggregation function cannot call another function?

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I am confused by this. I have a ag-grid in html:

```
<ag-grid-angular
    id="data_grid"
    title="Some Data"
    class="ag-theme-alpine ag-theme-material" 
    style="width: 2800px; height: 800px; margin-right: 1%; float: left; font-size: 16px !important"
    (gridReady)="onDataGridReady($event)"
    [rowData]="row_data" 
    [columnDefs]="column_defs"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    [autoGroupColumnDef]="autoGroupColumnDef"
    [groupDefaultExpanded]="groupDefaultExpanded"
    [animateRows]="true"
    [gridOptions]="grid_options">
  </ag-grid-angular>
```

Then in component file:

```
public defaultColDef: ColDef = {
    flex: 1,
    minWidth: 100,
    sortable: true,
    resizable: true,
  };
  public autoGroupColumnDef: ColDef = {
    minWidth: 200,
  };
  public groupDefaultExpanded = 1;
  public grid_options = {
    suppressAggFuncInHeader : true
  }
column_defs = [
    {headerName: 'A', field: 'many_As', rowGroup: true },
    {headerName: 'B', field: 'many_Bs', width: 250, aggFunc: this.agg_func },
  ];

agg_func(params: any) {
    ...
    another_func(); // the grid gets painted only if this line is commented out
    ...
}

another_func() {
    console.log('Hello?');
}
```

Now the problem is, if I let agg_func to call another_func, the grid will not be painted and this aggregation function does not get called at all.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely a problem with the "this" reference.

The functions are callbacks, being called from JavaScript code external to your class, so the reference winds up being incorrect.

When passing typescript class methods to external use as a callback, always use "arrow functions", which capture the "this" reference.

For example, change to:

```
const agg_func = (params: any) => {
    another_func(); 
}

const another_func = () => {
    console.log('Hello?');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That is working. However, how can I reference the data in the class in agg_func then?

Comment: I found "Registering Custom Functions" in https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/aggregation-custom-functions/ answers my above question.